# Auto-generate Interface in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, automation

I have a class in eclipse and will write an interface for it.

Is it possible, just like when auto generating getter/setter, to auto generate an interface form the class?

I appreciate your answer!!!

btw my eclipse version is indigo...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alt+Shift+T and "Extract interface"

Answer (score 3):

No need to click on only class name
Just Right click any where in the class.
   goto refractor
      select "Extract Interface"